# Difficulty using Protobuf 3.2 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use Protobuf in C++, but having trouble getting it to do anything meaningful.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

I built the protobuf [library](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/3.0.x).  I'm using the latest version from github.

I have created a .proto file as such:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Networking; 

message Robot{

message KinematicLinkProto {
    string name = 1;
    float x_pos = 2;
    float y_pos = 3;
    float z_pos = 4;
    float roll = 5;
    float pitch = 6;
    float yaw = 7;
    float x_scale = 8;
    float y_scale = 9;
    float z_scale = 10;
}

repeated KinematicLinkProto links = 1;

}
```

I compile this, and try to add it to a project:

```
#include "Robot.pb.h"



int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Networking::Robot robot_message;

    return 0;

}
```

My linker links libprotobuf.lib.  I am building it as /MD and libprotobuf is built as /MD.

For some reason, this simple program has the following two linker errors:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "private: static bool google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::default_serialization_deterministic_" (?default_serialization_deterministic_@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@0_NA) referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned char * __cdecl Networking::Robot::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray@Robot@Networking@@UEBAPEAEPEAE@Z)   


Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class google::protobuf::internal::ExplicitlyConstructed<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string" (?fixed_address_empty_string@internal@protobuf@google@@3V?$ExplicitlyConstructed@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@123@A) referenced in function "protected: void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::Clear<class google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<class Networking::Robot_KinematicLinkProto>::TypeHandler>(void)" (??$Clear@VTypeHandler@?$RepeatedPtrField@VRobot_KinematicLinkProto@Networking@@@protobuf@google@@@RepeatedPtrFieldBase@internal@protobuf@google@@IEAAXXZ)
```

I'm very confused - this is a very simple program.  What could I possibly be doing wrong?

EDIT:  A colleague compiled proto 3001000. This version does seem to work. I'm curious as to what about 3002000 breaks everything.

Comment: Are both the headers and libprotobuf.lib from version 3.2? Or might one of them be older? (You need to use exactly the same version.) Is libprotobuf.lib compiled with the same MSVC compiler flags, e.g. debug vs. release, static vs. dll, single-threaded vs. multi-threaded? The flags need to match between the library and your app.

Comment: Hi Kenton,  Yes, both the headers and libprotobuf come from the project I built.  libprotobuf is compiled with the same flags as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your exact code and Visual Studio 2015. I suggest you rebuild libprotobuf.lib with the latest sources (got mine here https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.2.0), following this: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md (if you use cmake to build a .sln, make sure you build the .sln that matches your version of Visual Studio, not necessarily 'Visual Studio 12 2013' like what's in the readme. I used ' Visual Studio 14 2015'). Its work with /MD or /MT (if libprotobuf is compiled accordingly of course)

Comment: @user650261 Have you tried with `GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION` before you do anything with protobufs?

Comment: I have tried all of these things, except building from the tag v.3.2.0 (I tried building from v.3.0.x and from master).  I will try v.3.2.0 asap.

Comment: What is SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray? The linker error is coming from that function, not from main.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using DLL, use

```
#define PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS
```